# Make a new cacti graph by summing the values ​​of another graph

Tags: monitoring, cacti, graph

I just start using cacti and I would like to know if it is possible to create a new graph from the sum of values in an other graph (not in the same one) .

For instance, I have a graph with:

Memory Free: 0,28G

Memory Buffers: 0,73G

Cache Memory: 1,17G

I'd like to get a new graph called "Available Memory Usage" and to graph 2,18G (0,73G + 0,28G + 1,17G)

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple data sources (e.g. every interface on a switch) from 0.8.7g onwards you can use the [Aggregate Plugin](http://docs.cacti.net/plugin:aggregate).

Otherwise you can use a [CDEF](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/cdeftutorial.en.html) with RPN notation, e.g. "a,b,c,+,+".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! i've followed your instructions and the following post: forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=8415 using CDEF:-)